# Latex equations in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, latex

I want to use GIMP to design a scientific poster.
Is there a plugin or something to insert and edit latex equations in GIMP?

Comment: Maybe too old: http://registry.gimp.org/node/24396

Comment: That really is not a great idea. Why wont you use LaTeX to produce the poster?

Comment: @LuísdeSousa It is faster/dirtier to move things around with the mouse. I just want to insert a couple of equations with latex, and be done with it quickly.

Comment: I can not see how it can be faster than strictly using LaTeX. You might profit from getting a bit more acquainted with LaTeX.

Comment: I actually have the same problem as you, I want to insert latex text in a gimp image and I don't kow how.  The only thing that occurred to me is to write it in latex, generate the pdf, take a screen shot and then copy paste.

Answer (score 2):

You can export the latex equation as an SVG (vector graphics which don't lose resolution with scaling) then import the SVG into your GIMP image.

This question references a number of simple online tools that let you entire a quick latex equation and generate an SVG without much hassle.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103282/convert-latex-to-svg-online

This question covers importing an SVG image into GIMP.

https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/11528/how-do-i-import-a-vector-path-from-inkscape-into-gimp